# bash NOT reading .bashrc on RHEL 6

Tags: bash, rhel, bashrc

machine A --RHEL 7 and updated.
machine B -- RHEL 6 and updated.

If I do this on A (RHEL 7)

> ssh B

I get in, like I should, but my .bashrc has NOT been run.
This is new behavior to me.  I *want* my `.bashrc` to be run on 
the machine B (RHEL 6).  I did diffs on the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and
`/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, and they are different but I don't see why
these should matter.

`ssh_config` differs only by whitespace and comments.

Yes, I saw the stuff but even with that it mangled the diff output because of the less than/greater than in it.  Is there something in there that I should care about?  I hacked and slashed, other than whitespace, comments, and environment
variable (`AcceptEnv`) here is what the diff boiled down to.

the 6 side

```
Protocol 2
```

the 7 side

```
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox
```

So, where do I look to find out why my `.bashrc` won't run?
My `.profile`, again:

```
alias lo='exit'
alias l='ls -CF'
alias ..='cd ..'
```

and my `.bashrc`:

```
PRINTER=its1
export PRINTER


DISPLAY=jgs:0.0
export DISPLAY

PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/opt/bin:/home/gl/bin:.

export PATH

PROXY=whiteproxy.arlut.utexas.edu:3128
export PROXY

cd /home/gl

if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

`/etc/bashrc` is stock.

Comment: Bash reads the files, not ssh.  Read the [Bash Guide for Beginners Chapter 3](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_01.html) or [this question on Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile) to learn how and when to use .bashrc and / or .bash_profile.  Also, your question says .bashrc isn't read on RHEL 7, then your example shows you logging in to RHEL 6.

Comment: I had a similar problem and the explanation that helped me get to the bottom of the issue was this: http://serverfault.com/a/593487/96078

Answer (score 4):

The ~/.bashrc file does not always get read: see [Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files) in the manual.

Does your ~/.bash_profile (or ~/.profile) invoke your .bashrc file? Often this appears in .profile files:

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the documentation is confusing but Bash's standard behavior is to source your "profile" (.bash_profile, .bash_login, .profile whichever it finds first in that order) on interactive login shells and .bashrc on interactive non-login shells.

Sshd typically spawns a login shell where opening an X11 terminal window is typically a non-login shell.

So you should not expect your .bashrc to be read when you ssh into a machine.

That said I generally recommend users add a line like the following to their "profile"

```
[[ -r ~/.bashrc ]] &&  source ~/.bashrc
```

Finally, /etc/bashrc is never directly read by Bush and you'll find no mention of it in the bash man page.  It's a file RedHat added and the expectation is that your ~/.bashrc file will source it. The default ~/.bashrc that should have been in your home directory when your account was created should be doing that. If not, you should find an example in the /etc/skel directory.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I sourced the `.bashrc` from the `.profile`. For me, this means the `.profile` must be empty except for running `.bashrc` to avoid circular references and other confusion.

As I've read in the man page, `sshd` should have invoked the `.bashrc`, but, oh well, I have a workaround.